# Why is the data being saved in the wrong order in this JSON? - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

As you can see I wanna save the same data fields x2 at the same time in DB.

But, because of its structure, in the first `<div>` there's not `language` and his options.

In the `EnviarCurriculumController.php` it's suppose  if there's not info there it's gonna be substitute by `''`, ergo `(NULL)` in DB.

But instead of that, the data of `language_option1` and `language_option2` are saving in the first row of DB, the one corresponding to the first `<div>`.

`language` is saving in his correct row in DB, but `language_option1` and `language_option2` in the previous one.

What should I do?

##### Data saved in DB

| nif | name | language | language_option1 | language_option2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ben | (NULL) | Intermediate | Rookie |
| 2 | John | English | (NULL) | (NULL) |

##### `EnviarCurriculum.php`

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EnviarCurriculum extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table';

    protected $primaryKey = 'ID_table';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nif',
        'name',
        'language',
        'language_option1',
        'language_option2'
    ];

    public function getRepeatedFields()
    {
       return json_decode($this->nif);
       return json_decode($this->name);
       return json_decode($this->language);
       return json_decode($this->language_option1);
       return json_decode($this->language_option2);
    }
}
```

##### `EnviarCurriculumController.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\enviarCurriculum;

use App\EnviarCurriculum;
use App\Configuracion;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EnviarCurriculumController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('enviar_curriculum', ['EnviarCurriculum' => new EnviarCurriculum()]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('enviar_curriculum', ['EnviarCurriculum' => new EnviarCurriculum()]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $nifs = $request->input('nif', []);
        $names = $request->input('name', []);
        $languages = $request->input('language', []);
        $language_options1 = $request->input('language_option1', []);
        $language_options2 = $request->input('language_option2', []);

         foreach ($nifs as $key => $nif) {
            EnviarCurriculum::create([
               'nif' => $nifs, 
               'name' => $names[$key]??'', 
               'language' => $languages[$key]??'',
               'language_option1' => $language_options1[$key]??'',
               'language_option2' => $language_options2[$key]??''
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

##### `enviar_curriculum.blade.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ route("store") }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        
        <div>
           <input type="text" name="nif[]" id="nif">

           <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name">
        </div>

        <br>

        <div>
           <input type="text" name="nif[]" id="nif">

           <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name">

           <input type="text" name="language[]" id="language">

           Speaking
           <select name="language_option1[]" id="language_option1">
              <option value="">Rookie</option>
              <option value="">Intermediate</option>
              <option value="">Expert</option>
           </select>

           Reading
           <select name="language_option2[]" id="language_option2">
              <option value="">Rookie</option>
              <option value="">Intermediate</option>
              <option value="">Expert</option>
           </select>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you do not have a good `HTML` to solve this.

You have these fields in this exact order:

1. Input text `nif[]`
2. Input text `name[]`
3. Input text `nif[]`
4. Input text `name[]`
5. Input text `language[]`
6. Input text `language_option1[]`
7. Input text `language_option2[]`

So, when you send all this info, you will have (for example) this data:

```json
{
    "nif": [
        "first nif",
        "second nif"
    ],
    "name": [
        "first name",
        "second name"
    ],
    "language": [
        "first language"
    ],
    "language_option1": [
        "first language_option1"
    ],
    "language_option2": [
        "first language_option2"
    ]
}
```

So, you have 2 `nif` and 2 `name` (index `0` and index `1`) but you have only index `0` for `language`, `language_option1` and `language_option2`. So your problem is your HTML, not your PHP code (that is correct).

Comment: And is any way to add a null index 0 without writing nothing in HTML?

Comment: @ElcondeLucanor no, only if you handle this information with Javascript. But I still do not recommend that as it is confusing, why do you have 2 entries for `nif` and `name` ? What does `nif` mean ?

Comment: Yeah, I know it's confusing but it's how is building the structure of the project I'm working and it's to late to change some things, it's a very old DB and in this form some data must be saved and other not, but if I don't send any data it appears a lot of errors. P.D. Nif is an europan identification, is the "ID" european, but in a DB can't be used as an usual ID.

Comment: So, before I help you with that, I need to know if we can get the first index of `nif` and `name` and store it somewhere else or similar. My idea is to first run the store code with only `nif` and `name`, and then use the second `nif` and `name` with the first index of the others variables. Do you want to store the data like your table in your question, but leave the first row with only `nif` and `name` and everything else `null`, and the second row have the second `nif` and `name` and the rest of the variables ? Can you update your question with desired result table ?